# View HTML of jQuery injected code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm thinking of using a couple jQuery tools/plugins to dynamically change the DOM of a page:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/appendDom

http://www.botsko.net/blog/2009/04/07/jquery-form-builder-plugin/

When the new DOM is changed, I can use Firebug to see the new elements as they are added, but I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions on how I can also build an .html page that can be saved off after a number of elements have been added.

My ultimate goal is to create an HTML Form Builder that will generate the HTML output so I can save the work as I go along.  I also want to take the output that was generated and upload it, have it parsed, which will allow me to continue working at another time.

Any thoughts on how to at least get the .html file would be great or tools that I can use.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the html of the generated object using `$(element).html()`, then POST it to a server-side script that will do the saving?

Comment: I assume you want to save the builder data for later? That is, take a generated form and continue to modify it using the tool?

Comment: It looks like the jQuery Form Builder plugin you linked can do exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you will just be needing the bits inside the body tag of the page you can get the HTML with `document.body.outerHTML`.

Comment: I believe `outerHTML` is not supported by Firefox.

Comment: innerHTML will work as well but you will just loose the body tags and anything on those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native `outerHTML`:

```
vat thehtml = $('#yourElement')[0].outerHTML;
```

Comment: No jQuery needed: `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML`

Comment: @Matt Ball - That's if he wants the whole page. The way I understood it, the OP only wants the HTML from certain particular elements...

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to get the HTML of the entire `<body>` section:

```
$('body').html();
```